# Polygonize a raster value using Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, gis, gdal

I have a .tiff raster file that I want to transfer into polygon shapefile data to use in GIS. [My code in Pycharm which is giving me 10 error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdqR6.jpg)

Code taken from here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#polygonize-a-raster-band

I found the code online and tried to fit my own data and bands into it but I am still getting errors. I have GDAL installed. If any more information is required to help, let me know as I am a complete novice!

Comment: You are trying to run python2 code with a python3 interpreter. Please only paste actual code and stack traces instead of screenshots.

Comment: Ok, noted, thank you. How do I go about updating the code to python 3? Below is the code in full if that is any use. Will I post again with the code in full?

Comment: Look up something like python2 python3 syntax changes on google. To get you started: `print(f'Unable to open {src_filename}')`

Comment: Welcome btw =) take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks a million! It's for a college project and I am completely lost.

Comment: If you really want to run python 2 code, you can also set up a python2 virtual/conda environment and point PyCharm to it. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c/ and https://medium.com/datareply/working-with-python-environments-anaconda-package-manager-and-ides-663e771b6ed8 are good resources to get you started. That said, python2 days are long gone so you'd probably be better off converting legacy code to python3.x syntax.